# How can I better understand the local ephemeral storage configuration on k8s

Tags: kubernetes

the docs (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#configurations-for-local-ephemeral-storage) say:

- the LocalStorageCapacityIsolation feature gate is enabled (the feature is on by default), and
- you have set up the node using one of the supported configurations for local ephemeral storage.

**If you have a different configuration, then the kubelet does not apply resource limits for ephemeral local storage.**

---

'you have set up the node using one of the supported configurations'

how to set up the configurations? and

'If you have a different configuration, then the kubelet does not apply resource limits for ephemeral local storage.'

what kind of configuration is 'different configuration'?

---

By the way I'd wanna know how can I quickly determine whether node supports apply resource limits for ephemeral local storage?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64824040/14801225) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59047219/14801225) not answer your question?

Comment: Thank you, but didn't answer my question. I don't know 'you have set up the node using one of the supported configurations', so what kind of configurations is the supported configurations.

Comment: I am worried that I turned on the ephemeral storage feature but it does not take effect